# Remove Cairo-dock(Gnome) desktop environment from the login

Tags: unity, login

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version its login is very nice but after i installed cairo-dock, cairo-dock(Gnome) desktop environment got added and i can choose either unity or cairo-dock(Gnome) desktop environment but i don't want to use cairo-dock(Gnome) desktop environment so i want to remove that cairo-dock option from login page.

I tried removing it by uninstalling cairo-dock desktop integration packages but the cairo-dock core is also uninstalling with it but i want to use cairo-dock. I also tried removing it from the cairo-dock settings but when i open settings as standard user the gnome option is not accessable and when i open settings as root user the gnome option is not viewable.

so please can some suggest me how to remove that option from the login screen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my solution

I found the desktop environment file that loads at login in usr/share/xsessions its 'Cairo-Dock (GNOME)' i deleted that file that solved my problem.